# On the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-ti)^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

It is known that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx=\sqrt{\pi}.$$ 
What about $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-ti)^2} dx, $$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $i=
\sqrt{-1}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Please avoid titles that are entirely in $\LaTeX$. Thanks.

Comment: Consider a counter-clockwised rectangle with four corners $\pm R$ and $\pm R - it$. With a simple application of Cauchy integral formula, you will reach the conclusion: $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x - it)^2} \; dx = \sqrt{\pi}.$$

Comment: There is a one-line proof that the answer is $\sqrt\pi$ for every real $t$ if complex analysis is allowed, and a somewhat longer one if only real analysis tools are allowed. Here is a typical example where answers to the questions *what do you know? what did you try? where are you stuck?* should be made clear in the post.

Comment: To substitute (formally, as they say) $x-it$ in the formula one gets for real $x$ and to pretend that $x-it$ is real, or that it is not but hey, who cares? is not what I call a proof. So no, this is not the *one-line proof* mentioned in my comment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-it)^2}\,dx = -i\int_{-\infty}^\infty -2(x-it)e^{-(x-it)^2}\,dx = -i e^{-(x-it)^2}\big|_{x=-\infty}^\infty = 0.
$$
So the integral is constant as a function of $t$, and you can set $t=0$ to find the constant.

Comment: I'm just astounded...

Comment: Beautiful Solution!

Answer (score 12):

We start with
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-(x-ti)^2} \mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{e}^{t^2} \cdot \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \cdot \cos(2 t x) \mathrm{d}x
$$
Now, let $\mathcal{I}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \cdot \cos(2 t x) \mathrm{d}x$. Then
$$
   \mathcal{I}^{\prime}(t) = -2\int_{-\infty}^\infty x \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \cdot \sin(2 t x) \mathrm{d}x =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(2 t x) \cdot \mathrm{d} \left( \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \right) \stackrel{\text{by parts}}{=}\\  -2t \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(2 t x) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \mathrm{d} x = -2 t \mathcal{I}(t)
$$
Thus
$$
  \mathcal{I}(t) = \mathcal{I}(0) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-t^2} = \sqrt{\pi} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-t^2}
$$

Hence
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-(x-ti)^2} \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\pi}
$$

Comment: Very thanks for answer.

Comment: I usually preferred real analysis methods to complex analysis ones when calculating integrals on real lines. Now I'm a bit alarmed by your answer, since it gives me a feeling that I began to forget real analysis methods. I threw you an upvote for that.

Comment: There is no need to decompose the exponential into a sine and cosine part. Write the integral on the right side at the top as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2+2xti}dx$ and call it $I(t)$. Then $I'(t) = -2tI(t)$ using integration by parts (Sasha, you lost a factor of 2 when you get just $-tI(t)$) with $u = -ie^{2xti}$ and $dv = -2xe^{-x^2}dx$.

Comment: @sos440: why would you prefer real analysis methods to complex analysis methods to evaluate real integrals, after seeing how incredible the residue theorem is for such computations?

Comment: @KCd, There is no decomposition in Sasha's proof. The sine part disappeared simply because it is an odd function. But I agree that the factor of 2 is lost since the second equation.

Comment: I have fixed the missing factor.Thanks!

Comment: Well, there is no logically acceptable reason why I prefer real analytic methods. Rather, it's because my aesthetic sensitivity toward integrals has been developed over completely real analytic basis...

Comment: Why even expand out the $(x-ti)^2$? If $J(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-ti)^2}\,dt$, then $$J'(t) = -i\int_{-\infty}^\infty -2(x-ti)e^{-(x-ti)^2}\,dt = -i e^{-(x-ti)^2}\big|_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} = 0.$$ So $J(t)$ is constant.

Comment: @NickStrehlke This is beautiful! Please post this as an answer

Comment: @NickStrehlke: You should use dx instead of dt in both of the integrals you wrote.

Comment: @Sasha I put it as an answer; thanks. (+1 by the way.)

Comment: @KCd you are right. I posted an answer and fixed it there.

Answer (score 4):

First show that
$$
F(z) := \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-z)^2} dx
$$
exists for all $z \in \mathbb C$, and that it is analytic in $z$.
Then evaluate it for some convenient values (say $z$ real)
that have a limit point.  Then you may conclude the value for all $z$.