# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\cos x \, dx$

Tags: calculus

Can you help me with this?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\cos x \, dx$$

Comment: Is it possible to do $\int e^{-x^2} e^{ix} dx$ and then take the real part?

Comment: What Maesumi said; use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123961/on-the-integral-int-infty-infty-e-x-ti2-dx?rq=1.

Comment: @Maesumi : Thinking about computing your integral in terms of the Fourier transform of $e^{-x^2}$ might be a useful way to get this done quick.

Comment: This is a special case of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/317249).

Answer (score 23):

Method 1 (Contour integration):

$$f(x)=e^{-x^2}$$

Let $C$ be a contour that is a rectangle with vertices at $-R$,$R$, $R+i/2$ and $-R+i/2$.  Letting $R\to\infty$, the integral along the sides disappears, so by Cauchy's Integral Theorem:

$$
0 = \oint_C f(z) = \\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, dx-\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x+i/2)\, dx = \\
\sqrt{\pi}-e^{1/4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))\, dx
$$

Taking the real parts of both sizes, we obtain

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(x)\,dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{\sqrt[4] e}$$

---

Method 2 (Differentiating under the Integral Sign):

$$I(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \cos(a x)\,dx$$
$$I'(a) = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty x e^{-x^2} \sin(a x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2} \sin(a x)\bigg|_{-\infty}^\infty-\frac{a}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)\,dx = -\frac{a I(a)}{2}$$

Because $I(0)=\sqrt{\pi}$ we have $I(a) = \sqrt \pi e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}}$.  Then $I(1) = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{\sqrt[4] e}$ is the answer.

---

Method 3 (Summation):

$$\cos x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

so

$$
I = 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos x\,dx = \\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\, dx=\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} x^{2n}\, dx=\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}2\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2} x^{2n}\, dx \stackrel{x\mapsto \sqrt x}{=}\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x} x^{n-1/2}\, dx =\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \frac{\sqrt{\pi} (2n)!}{4^n n!} = \\
\sqrt \pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n \frac{1}{n!} = \\
\frac{\sqrt \pi}{\sqrt[4] e}
$$

Where [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) is employed and the change of summation and integration must be justified.

Comment: You say "take real parts" but the entire quantity is real. I presume there is a typo?

Comment: Why we can take real parts?
Is another way to calculate this without using contours and complex numbers?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Thanks.

Comment: @Dariusz Added a differentiation under the integrand method.

Comment: I like [Method 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/317350)

Comment: @Argon Nice answers (+1).

Comment: For those who may wonder why one could pass the differentiation under the integral sign: Let $g_{a,R}:= -\int_{-R}^R x e^{-x^2} \sin(a x)\,dx.$ Note that $\sin(a x)\le 1\, \forall a$, we know the series $g_{a,R}$ is uniformly convergent in $a$. Then using the Leibniz rule (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), we are done.